# How can I be able to access the label and value of a constant/variable in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am using Mirror to access the children of my struct like this:

```
struct TestType {

    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    
    var value: String {
        return firstName + lastName
    }
}
```

use case:

```
let person: TestType = TestType(firstName: "Tim", lastName: "Cook")


for property in Mirror(reflecting: person).children  {
    print("label: \(property.label!)", "value: \(property.value)")
}
```

results:

> label: firstName value: Tim

> label: lastName value: Cook

Now my goal is do the same thing for the `person` constant as well, with that said, I want be able to access the label of `person` which is **person** and the value of it, the result should look like this:

> label: person value: Tim Cook

How can i do this in Swift?

Comment: Is `person` a global constant?

Comment: Yes, it is a global constant.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) why do you want to do this?

Comment: In my last question I was trying to access the didSet of a Type in general to put my logic code there for removing some label from a set, now I thought that would be good idea that I use a dic with key of label of constant from this question and the custom wished label from last question as value. PS: This current question is also a question stand alone for itself. I want to know how i can get access to a constant label with Mirror.

Comment: So this and your last question is more of a compile time issue rather than a runtime issue?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I have no idea why need to use Mirror here) would be great if you would describe it in as a comment below this answer. I would appreciate it)

but the reason why you can't what you need is because of `Mirror` can't see computed properties, as far as I know. Any way you can customise your init method to reach what you need. But remember that using `Mirror` is too expensive, for example: if it in inherited object it will parse every single thing in parent classes which could be accessible for Mirror

```
struct TestType {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let person: String

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        person = [firstName, lastName].joined(separator: " ")
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mis understood! As you can see for yourself in my question I could made it so far that I could mirror the properties of my custom Type, so I think that would not be so hard for me to do the same thing for a property called person in your answer. For your information I mentioned in title of question in body of question and in my comments as well that "access the label and value of a constant/variable" not another property! Also some other user asked if that is defined as global, and i answered yes as well. So I am not sure how your answer is going to solve the issue.

Comment: Also I see from your reputation that you are new in answering or you are not an active user, in this platform we are not deforming or changing the structure of codes, but solving issues and bugs and errors. If you look to my question, can you see a property called person in TestType struct? If you are unable to see or find a property called person, that means I do not want it, it makes no sense putting firstName and lastName and person beside together!

Comment: PS: your logic in your answer is unnecessary complicated and there is no benefit in it! You are building an array and then using a method called joined! you could simply use: `self.person = firstName + " " + lastName`

Comment: @ioscoder The code in the answer is not "unnecessarily complicated". Your example works as well. So does `self.person = "\(firstName) \(lastName)"`. They're just stylistic differences. You would need to do the operations at a *massive* scale to see any difference.

Comment: @jnpdx: I do not know about your job or if you are in developer job, if you write the code you supported in this answer for the goal of making a string from 2 other strings, you would probably get fired.

Comment: @ioscoder No, I really don't think that's true. It's a matter of stylistic preference. You don't prefer it, which is fine. But others may. And I find it extremely unlikely it would be a fireable offense at any reasonable workplace. Most likely in CR someone would just say that their code style prefers a different method and ask the writer to change it if they thought it was important.